sqldelight plugin not generating .sq files android studio
The SqlDelight plugin not generating files with the .sq extension. If I can manage to create a file then not able to write or edit this. Why I am facing this issue?


Are you seeing any error when the file is trying to be created? Can you share what you are doing?

sorry, no error

Please provide a [mre] so we can try it out for ourselves. Make sure you do not post your entire code, we only need the shortest version possible that reproduces the problem.

@Leviathan I have updated the question with gif file to clarify. Now you can see I am not able to write next character

Finally, it started working after uninstalling and re-install. also, you may need to restart your IDE or Machine.

Thanks to your answer, I thought about disabling and re-enabling the plugin before trying to uninstall and reinstall, and that fixed the issue for me.
